# Wordpress Error 500 after migration

Tags: wordpress, migration, fatal-error, pluggable

I'm getting an error on my WordPress website when I moved it from one server to the other
The error I get is error 500 This page isn’t working

I get this error on both the website and the administrator

When I check the log I get the following error

Got error 'PHP message: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function _wp_get_current_user() in /public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 70`

I'm thinking I'm getting this error because there is no current user since the website has just moved location and its some caching error or something

When googling this error I get many issues with plugins, but since the website works on another server I'm assuming that plugins shouldn't be the issue.

I have no idea if that's how it works, but I'd really prefer to fix this without having to hack the Wordpress files too much.
Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could have many reasons. 
In particular, I can't relate to anything, but this could be incompatibility issues with your new hosting. Its best to contact your hosting provider.

This could be:

- lack of some required PHP extension
- lack of resources
- corrupted backup file

I would first disable all plugins (by renaming the plugins folder to something else) and test if the issue is still persists.

Comment: Appearantly it was something woth the hosting provider, they've solved it

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing PHP version in Server Control Panel fixed the problem after migrating from Linux server to Windows.

i.e In Plesk control panel: Open Related Domain > Go to Hosting Settings > PHP support (PHP version) and change it (for me, downgrading version solved 500 Error).